# RxJava subscribe only for specific key

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java3

I'm receiving an infinite stream of events, lets say `Observable<Event>` where `Event(userId, payload)`. I have to provide functionality which allows subscribing users for their events. `Observable<Event>` is a hot source, but it doesn't matter as I can drop events if there are no interested users on it. I'm trying to do it in pure streaming fashion using RxJava API but it seems difficult for me. What did I try:

1. Do it with the least effort, using built-in operators.

```java
   Observable<Event> events =; //;
   events = events.publish().refCount();
        
   Observable<Event> subscribeUser(int userId) {
       return events.filter(it -> it.userId == userId);
   }
```

Works great, the problem is its just slow for my case - I don't need multicast to all subscribers and then filter if it not belongs to any user. Imagine there is tens of thousands users and 1000 events per second - O(n) complexity is too much for me - I need some hashing i think.

2. `PublishSubject`

```java
 ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, PublishSubject<Event>> subscriptions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 Observable<Event> events =; //
 events.subscribe(event -> /*pushing on user subject*/);

 Observable<Event> subscribeUser(int userId) {
    return subscriptions.putIfAbsent(userId, PublishSubject.create())
   .doOnTerminate(() -> subscriptions.remove(userId))
 }
```

This requires more coding (much more than in example above) for managing subscriptions, it's not pure streaming also `PublishSubject` is designed for multiple subscribers so it takes a little more space for internal arrays which I don't need, because I have only exactly one user per subject.

3. `groupBy()` operator
   I can group events by userId producing `GroupedObservable` streams, then I can just `.ignoreElements()` until there is no subscription but I don't know how can I connect these two together. On one side I have hot `Observable` stream of `GroupedObservable<Integer, Event>` and then incoming `Observable<Event> subscribeUser(int userId)` request. How can I say: "hey, from now don't drop elements because there is someone interested on it" and return `GroupedObservable` as response for request?
4. custom `Observable`

Problem here is `Observable.create(subscriber -> )` subscriber doesn't have information about its key (userId) - I also have no control over `subscribe()` method so I cannot pass there my custom implementation and retrieve key after casting or somehow. It's also bad because I need to manage state by myself.

5. `lift()` with custom operator
   Similar problems to 4, even worse because I have no control over creating `Observable` here so I need to also prevent multiple connections to source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2) is the most straightforward. Option 4 would require more cleverness in coding an `Observable`.

```java
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Observer<Event>> observers = ...

void signal(Event event) {
   var observer = observers.get(event.userId);
   if (observer != null) {
       observer.onNext(event);
   }
}

Observable<Event> observeUser(int userId) {
    return Observable.unsafeCreate(observer -> {
        var remove = Disposable.fromAction(() -> observers.remove(userId));
        subscriber.onSubscribe(remove);
        observers.put(userId, observer);
    });
}
```